# Bash script conditional, else not working

Tags: bash

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo pkexec ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 1000000
echo $?
result=$?

if [[ result -eq 0 ]]
then
  echo "Node will initialize"
else
  echo "Node will not initialize"
fi
```

It will just read the exit status of the above terminal command and will print out messages according to the condition. As I run the script, even the result is equal to 0 or 1 or 2, it will print "Node will initialize". What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order matters!

With `result=$?` you get the result of the `echo $?` command.

Do the assignment first, and print the value of `$result` instead:

```
sudo pkexec ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 1000000
result=$?
echo $result
```

Comment: Thank you so much!, I haven't thought of that. It is now working. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** based on the comment by rowboat:

While `-eq` inside `[[ ... ]]` indeed also imposes numeric context and makes `[[ result -eq 0 ]]` feasible, arithmetic interpretation is easier to express by `(( .... ))`. In this example, this would be

```
sudo pkexec ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 1000000
result=$?

if (( result == 0 ))
then
  echo "Node will initialize"
else
  echo "Node will not initialize, exit code: $result"
fi
```

Of course if `pkexec` only returns the exit codes 0 and 1, respectively if we don't want to differentiate between the various non-zero exit codes, we can write even easier

```
if sudo pkexec ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 1000000
then
  echo "Node will initialize"
else
  echo "Node will not initialize"
fi
```

Comment: I tried replacing -eq with == and it prints "Node will not initialize" even if the result is equal to 0 or 1. I guess -eq works fine by me but still thank you for your input. 

But what does -eq differ from ==??

Comment: @racaraca69 : Did you write the round parenthesis? Copy and paste the exact command you are using.

Comment: The `[[` does do arithmetic evaluation e.g. `bash -c '[[ 1+1 -eq 2 ]] && echo OK'`

Comment: Yes, but the point in my answer was about dereferencing the variable. In the original program, the OP did not derference the variable, and I showed that this would be unnecessary if numeric context would be used. Also, for general calculations, the numeric context will make life easier than  using `[[ ... ]]`. Think about expressions such as `if (( (a+b)*c <= d )); then ...`.

Comment: I agree that `(())` is easier, but `[[ \(a+b\)*c -le d ]]` would work.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that bash allows expressions and implicit expansion of variables here too. Good to know!

Comment: @racaraca69 : I fixed my answer, based on the comments received by _rowboat_.

Comment: Wow! changing brackets to parenthesis works. thank you for explanation